# Filter out unwanted string in map

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

EDIT:

I have string like this:

```
String value1 = "xyzz#@#$%helloworldtestdata"
```

or

```
String value1 = "xyzztestcase" or String value1 = "notincludedxyzztestcase"
```

and

```
String value2 = "xxxyz! xyyz xyzz xyyz"
```

I am trying to filter out each string with their corresponding word. So far, I have this code and it was fine but not with the value1

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("xxxyz!", "test1");
    map.put("xxxyz?", "test2");
    map.put("xyyz", "test3");
    map.put("xyzz", "test4");

    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        if (value2.contains(s)) {
            value2 = value2.replaceAll(s, map.get(s));
        } 
    }
```

If I use the value2 here is the output I am getting:

```
test1 test3 test4 test3
```

But if I use the value1 I am getting this one:

```
test4#@#$%helloworldtestdata
```

How can I filter out the part that is not included on my map, key but not messing the spaces of value1?

Comment: What do you mean by filter out? If you want to just eliminate it, `String.replace("begone", "")`

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.  Please clarify your objective; maybe if you were to post 4-5 different examples of input ***and expected output*** we could deduce the rules you are trying to implement.

Comment: Sorry, I have to edit the post. What I am trying to do is only get those word that is on the map and eliminate other strings that are not included. I hope that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show a complete working code example? It should compile and run and produce the exact output that you see on your end.

Comment: Also please explain in more detail what you mean by "I am trying to filter out each string with their corresponding word."

Answer (score -1):

The `replaceAll` method is simply taking whatever your value for s (the keys in your map) is and replacing it with your value for s in your map. From what you described, something similar to what you want to do is do a 
`value2 = value2.replaceAll("#@#$%helloworldtestdata", "");`

This will replace the string `#@#$%helloworldtestdata` with an empty one.

To do this reassignment in your method, you would want to add the following to your map:
`map.put("#@#$%helloworldtestdata", "test5");` 
(test5 is just an example)

Adding this will not mess up your spaces in value1 because the string it looking to replace (the regex) has not been changed for any of the other strings you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

i dont know about i use, but here i use in my code.

var = "how to set love"

i just use one set to get value i want.
print var[:2]

## is wil get "how"

and yes if you fil replace just use
x = var.replace("i will be", "how to")

## it will get "i will be set love"

correct me if i flase